# Multitask deep learning with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Have someone tried doing multitask deep learning with TensorFlow? That is, sharing the bottom layers while not sharing the top layers.  An example with simple illustration would help a lot.

Answer (score 11):

There is an similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861112/how-to-do-multitask-deep-learning-with-tensorflow), the answer used keras.

It's similar when just using tensorflow. The idea is this: we can define multiple outputs of a network, and thus multiple loss functions (objectives). We then tell optimizer to minimize a combined loss function, usually using a linear combination.

A concept diagram [image: Multi Task Deep Learning Diagram]

This diagram is drawn according to this [paper](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj54p_W86_QAhUDHJQKHeKoAXEQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Fpubs%2Farchive%2F42241.pdf&usg=AFQjCNER9_KAZYR4LCjFbKP9FL_cmXeHgg).

Let's say we are training a classifier that predict the digit in the image, with maximum 5 digits per image. Here we defined 6 output layer: `digit1`, `digit2`, `digit3`, `digit4`, `digit5`, `length`. The `digit` layer should output 0~9 if there is such a digit, or `X`(*substitute it with an real number in practice*) if there isn't any digit **in its position**. Same thing for `length`, it should output 0~5 if the image contains 0~5 digit, or `X` if it contains more than 5 digits.

Now to train it, we just add up all the cross entropy loss of each softmax function:

```
# Define loss and optimizer
lossLength = tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(length_logits, true_length)), 1e-37, 1e+37))
lossDigit1 = tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(digit1_logits, true_digit1)), 1e-37, 1e+37))
lossDigit2 = tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(digit2_logits, true_digit2)), 1e-37, 1e+37))
lossDigit3 = tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(digit3_logits, true_digit3)), 1e-37, 1e+37))
lossDigit4 = tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(digit4_logits, true_digit4)), 1e-37, 1e+37))
lossDigit5 = tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(digit5_logits, true_digit5)), 1e-37, 1e+37))

cost = tf.add(
        tf.add(
        tf.add(
        tf.add(
        tf.add(cL,lossDigit1),
        lossDigit2),
        lossDigit3),
        lossDigit4),
        lossDigit5)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```