# how to do multitask deep learning with tensorflow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

Does anyone know how to do multitask deep learning with TensorFlow? That is, sharing the bottom layers while not sharing the top layers. Could you kindly share some example code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multitask deep learning with Tensorflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591195/multitask-deep-learning-with-tensorflow)

Answer (score 6):

Keras with the TensorFlow backend can easily do this. The functional API was designed for these use cases. Take a look at the [functional API guide.](http://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) Here is an LSTM example that shared layers, taken from the above guide:

```python
# this layer can take as input a matrix
# and will return a vector of size 64
shared_lstm = LSTM(64)

# when we reuse the same layer instance
# multiple times, the weights of the layer
# are also being reused
# (it is effectively *the same* layer)
encoded_a = shared_lstm(tweet_a)
encoded_b = shared_lstm(tweet_b)

# we can then concatenate the two vectors:
merged_vector = merge([encoded_a, encoded_b], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)

# and add a logistic regression on top
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged_vector)

# we define a trainable model linking the
# tweet inputs to the predictions
model = Model(input=[tweet_a, tweet_b], output=predictions)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([data_a, data_b], labels, nb_epoch=10)
```

When you train a Keras model with multiple outputs, you can define a loss function for each output, and Keras will optimize over the sum of all losses, which is pretty useful.