# MTL with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement the 'Multi Task Learning' (MTL) paradigm with TensorFlow. There is a good short description for MTL in the [Deep Learning book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/regularization.html#pf12).

I'm using the wiki-imdb faces dataset, with labels 'gender' and 'age':

- 450x450 pixels image
- Gender is a one hot-vector of dimension 2. (male or female)
- Age is a one hot-vector of dimension 2. (age over 40, or not)

The MTL approach consist of two kinds of parameter:

- Generic parameters: across all the tasks, lower layers of the network.
- Task-specific parameters: upper layers of the network.

How do I get two kinds of labeled data into the net? How do I "split" the neuron and create a label-specific neuron and get two outputs from the net? I would like to implement it via a Multi-Layer Perceptron or via a Convolutional Neural Network.

I already implement a "single task learning" approach for each tasks.

My net looks like this:

```
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
   # Hidden layer with RELU activation
   layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
   layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
   # Hidden layer with RELU activation
   layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
   layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
   # Output layer with linear activation
   out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
   return out_layer
```

I know of a Keras model exists, but I would like try to do it in TensorFlow.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/07/multi-task-learning-tensorflow-part-1.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multitask deep learning with Tensorflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591195/multitask-deep-learning-with-tensorflow)